# Add another condition to avoid combining specific data

Tags: javascript

I am making a function where 2 data will be joined if they have the same weight.

Currently, i have a target where entries with the **same CLASS should not be matched/joined**. I have provided my codes below with my current output and target

```js
const source = [
    {
        entryID: 1,
        entryName: "player1",
        weight: 1900,
        class: ['a', 'b'],

    },
    {
        entryID: 2,
        entryName: "player2",
        weight: 1900,
        class: ['a', 'b'],

    },
    {
        entryID: 3,
        entryName: "player3",
        weight: 1900,
        class: ['c', 'd'],

    },
    {
        entryID: 4,
        entryName: "player4",
        weight: 1900,
        class: ['c', 'd'],
    },

];

console.log(combine(source))

function combine(data = [], different = 0, maxGroupSize = 2) {
    const groups = [], related = [], sortedData = [...data].sort((a, b) => a.weight - b.weight),
        alreadyInRela = (setX, eName) => {
            let list = [...setX, eName]
            return related.some(rela => list.every(l => rela.has(l)))
        };
    
    sortedData.forEach((el, indx) => {
        let place = groups.findIndex( // find a place in a group forEach element, use indx as track
            g => g.names.size < maxGroupSize              // is the group incomplete ?
                && !g.names.has(el.entryName)             // is entryName not in the group list (names Set) ?
                && (el.weight - g.weight) <= different
                && !alreadyInRela(g.names, el.entryName) // is (entryName + group list) does not already used ?
        )

        if (place < 0) { // not found -> create new group
            let names = new Set().add(el.entryName)                      // create new group
            groups.push({ names, indxs: [indx], weight: el.weight })  // group constitutive info 
            related.push(names)                                      // keep track of group list
        } else { // find a place in a group
            groups[place].names.add(el.entryName)  // related list is also updated
            groups[place].indxs.push(indx)        // add indx to retreive element in sortedData 
        }
    });

    return groups.reduce((r, g, i) => { // build result
        if (g.indxs.length > 1) {
            let key = `${i}_` + g.indxs.map(x => sortedData[x].weight).join('_')
            r[key] = []
            g.indxs.forEach(x => r[key].push(sortedData[x]))
        }
        return r
    }, {})
}
```

Current Output (As we can see here, even tho the entries have the same **CLASS**, they are still joined/combined):

```js
{
    0_1900_1900: [
        {
            class: ["a", "b"],
            entryID: 1,
            entryName: "player1",
            weight: 1900
        },
        {
            class: ["a", "b"],
            entryID: 2,
            entryName: "player2",
            weight: 1900
        }
    ],
    1_1900_1900: [
        {
            class: ["c", "d"],
            entryID: 3,
            entryName: "player3",
            weight: 1900
        },
        {
            class: ["c", "d"],
            entryID: 4,
            entryName: "player4",
            weight: 1900
        }
    ]
}
```

Target output (As we can see here, the entries with the same **CLASS** are not joined/combined. This is what i need to aim for):

```js
{
    0_1900_1900: [
        {
            class: ["a", "b"],
            entryID: 1,
            entryName: "player1",
            weight: 1900
        },
        {
            class: ["c", "d"],
            entryID: 3,
            entryName: "player3",
            weight: 1900
        }
    ],
    1_1900_1900: [
        {
            class: ["a", "b"],
            entryID: 2,
            entryName: "player2",
            weight: 1900
        },
        {
            class: ["c", "d"],
            entryID: 4,
            entryName: "player4",
            weight: 1900
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: what is the condition?

Comment: They will be joined if they have the same weight, but if they have the same CLASS, they shouldn't be joined.

Comment: ok. how about `0_1900_1900` and `1_1900_1900`? what's the meaning of that?

Comment: so if the `maxGroupSize = 3`, then the key will become like this `0_1900_1900_1900` and `1_1900_1900_1900`?

Comment: My target is only to join 2 entries. It is like having a match (1 vs 1). I just need to add another condition where entries have the same class should not be matched/joined.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const source = [
    {
        entryID: 1,
        entryName: "player1",
        weight: 1900,
        class: ['a', 'b'],

    },
    {
        entryID: 2,
        entryName: "player2",
        weight: 1900,
        class: ['a', 'b'],

    },
    {
        entryID: 3,
        entryName: "player3",
        weight: 1900,
        class: ['c', 'd'],

    },
    {
        entryID: 4,
        entryName: "player4",
        weight: 1900,
        class: ['c', 'd'],

    },

];

source.sort((a, b) => a.weight - b.weight);

const uniqueClass = source.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    if (!prev.find(p => p.class.every((pc, i) => pc === curr.class[i]))) {
        prev.push(curr);
        source.splice(source.findIndex(s => s.entryID === curr.entryID), 1);
    }
    return prev;
}, []);

const groupWeightWithUniqueClass = uniqueClass.reduce((prev, curr, i) => {
    const found = source.findIndex(s => s.weight === curr.weight && s.class.some((sc, i) => sc !== curr.class[i]));
    prev[`${i}_${curr.weight}_${curr.weight}`] = [curr, source[found]];
    source.splice(found, 1);
    return prev;
}, {});

console.log(groupWeightWithUniqueClass);
```

Comment: I'll study about this if i can apply this on my current code.  Thanks